# how to deal with unique data use d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

there are 200 records,for example:

```
[
   {time:"Thu Nov 07 2013 13:09:08",value:"10"},
   {time:"Thu Nov 07 2013 11:09:08",value:"30"},
   {time:"Thu Nov 07 2013 11:09:08",value:"25"},
   ....more
   {time:"Thu Nov 06 2013 10:09:08",value:"65"},
   {time:"Tue Aug 06 2013 16:54:31",value:"25"},
   {time:"Tue Aug 06 2013 16:54:31",value:"45"},
]
```

there are one or two unique recodes that the time is too early.
when i draw a line use time as xAxis, beacuse of the unique recodes ( `{time:"Tue Aug 06 2013 16:54:31",value:"25"},{time:"Tue Aug 06 2013 16:54:31",value:"45"}`) ,the line has a blank at between Nov to Aug .
how can i deal with the records what is unique and  several  .
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an unique id field to your data if you want to draw both or remove one (and display an average value or whatever is suitable)